# UIImagePicker Camera Memory Warning stops Image from being set to UIImageView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a modal which displays a UIImagePicker and allows the user to take a photo which then gets put into a UIImageView.

Every now and then I get a memory warning 'Received Memory Warning' and the UIImageView does not get assigned. The App is fairly simple and it's not using a lot of memory, and it seems that a lot of the time this has to do with the ImagePicker as a separate process. This only happens when using the camera, and it happens about one in five times.

There's a [lot of talk about this online](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=recieved%20a%20memory%20warning%20when%20taking%20photo%20with%20camera%20ios&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#hl=en&client=safari&rls=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=recieved%20a%20memory%20warning%20when%20taking%20photo%20with%20camera%20uiimagepicker%20ios&oq=recieved%20a%20memory%20warning%20when%20taking%20photo%20with%20camera%20uiimagepicker%20ios&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=55542l57154l0l57462l14l14l0l0l0l13l379l4332l2-7.7l14l0&gs_l=serp.3...55542l57154l0l57463l14l14l0l0l0l13l379l4332l2-7j7l14l0.cgsbsh.1.&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=50ee6cffd01544e7&biw=1440&bih=752), and most of the answers say to 'handle the warning appropriately'; but I"m not sure what that means - I just want the taken photo to show up in the ImageView! It seems to happen before I can do anything about it in the UIImagePicker delegate.

What can I do to mitigate this?

Here's the didFinishPickingImage Delegate:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    //set background for image select button, put image reference somewhere to copy image to documents folder and insert into modular's sentence object.
    //ImagePicker.jpg needs it's border set to 1px black.

    NSLog(@"imagePickerController: selectedimage: %@", selectedImage);

    imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
    [imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton.layer setBorderWidth: 1.0];
    [imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    [imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
    imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton.image = selectedImage;

    imageViewBehindPhotoBigButton.hidden = NO;
    [choosePhotoBigButton setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    choosePhotoBarImage.hidden = NO; 
    choosePhotoText.hidden = NO;

    addButton.enabled = YES;

    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {      
        //because iPad uses a pop up - we don't want to dismiss modals here!
        [imagePopupController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    }else{
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
    }



}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was to implement threading when scaling / handling the image from the UIImagePickerController. There's a really good discussion that I used [here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/wordpress/tag/uiimagepickercontroller/).

Comment: hi, thanks for your link. So far it seems to work - without "Memory Warning". I also thought of this before I landed here, but what prevented me from doing it was because I thought it might consume more processing juice / memory while scaling down the image, but it seems to work. Thanks again.